# Getting data from 2 tables with relationship with WHERE clausule

Tags: php, twig

I've been following the PHP Authentication Tutorial en managed to get it working.

Now I want to add a function to my navbar. I will try to explain and hopefully someone has the answer.

I have the 2 user tables, users and user_permissions.
In the user table there are additional columns named `district_id`, `district`, `gemeente_id` and `gemeente`. I also have 2 extra tables in the database called `districten` and `gemeenten`.

The `districten` table has 2 colums. `id` and `district` which holds the unique `ID` and the `name`. The `gemeente` table has at least these 3 columns `id`, `district_id` and `gemeente`.

Here is what I would like to happen:

When the user logs in the query will give a result in an `<ul>` in the navbar where it will show all values (column `gemeente`) from the `gemeenten` table where the user has been assigned to.

Example:

> User ZZZ is assigned to district A.
>  
>   This district holds 4 gemeenten : City 1, City 2, City 3 and City 4
>   When the user logs in, he should
>   only see the cities from the District A.

I don't know how to get this working in Slim2 Framework and integrated in the PHP Authentication code. So any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to normalize your table and get rid of redundant information since it's hard to maintain it in relational database(I assume here you're using relational database like MySQL).

So basically each user is assigned to gemeente, each gemeente assigned to district and district in his turn has cities(gemeenten). In user table you only need the `gemeente_id`. The schema of `districten` and `gemeente` seems fine.

There are two way how to retrieve needed data: by running 2 queries(1 for fetch user's district; 2nd for fetch district's cities) and run everything in one query. Which way to choose is up to you.

1st approach:

`SELECT d.id FROM district AS d LEFT JOIN gemeente AS g ON g.district_id=d.id LEFT JOIN user AS u ON u.gemeente_id=g.id WHERE u.id=<user_id>`

`SELECT g.id, g.gemeenten from gemeente as g where g.district_id = <res_of_prev_query>`

2nd approach:

`SELECT 
    g.id, g.gemeenten 
FROM gemeente AS g 
LEFT JOIN 
    districten AS d 
ON g.district_id=d.id 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT district_id, u.id AS user_id 
    FROM gemeente as gg 
    INNER JOIN user AS u 
    ON u.gemeente_id=gg.id) AS ud 
ON ud.district_id=g.district_id 
WHERE ud.user_id=<user_id>`

You need transform this query to your ORM/ActiveRecord, run it and display the `ul` list

**UPD:** I've updated my answer. Thanks @DarkBee for pointing me to my mistake

Comment: I'd say the user table only needs the `gemeente_id` with which you then can retrieve the correct `district_id`, otherwise you don't know where your user lives

Comment: @DarkBee yeah, you're right. Let me update my answer. Thanks

Comment: @YuriyNedostup: Thanks so far. Now I am using Slim2 with Eloquent and Twig. I am so new to this framework stuff that I don't know how to transform it to this ORM of Slim2.